# How to resolve the problem of white spaces in wildcardQuery elasticsearch java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder

With **elasticsearch** **java**, when I used:

`QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(FIELDNAME, SEARCH_VALUE))`

The search query didn't detect all the expression of the `SEARCH_VALUE`, it takes into consideration only the first word and ignores the rest.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you show us a test case, the SEARCH_VALUE you are trying with and the result you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

`SEARCH_VALUE` should be the wildcard pattern used with the search query.
A wildcard pattern should not contain white spaces, you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/817-6252-10/npgwldcrd.html) the supported patterns and characters you can use.

You can try instead with the other `QueryBuilders` methods from the [Javadoc](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.9.2/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.html).